# Not able to open web page with added cookies in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have logged in to website and now trying to load website URL again and expecting it logins automatically as i am adding cookies from already logged in page, but it generates below exception,

code:

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

driver = Chrome("C:/Users/jupiter/PycharmProjects/webdriver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")

driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button").click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Login')]").click()

username =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/input")

username.send_keys("xyz")

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input")

password.send_keys("abc@xyz")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/button").click()

cookies =driver.get_cookies()

driver = Chrome("C:/Users/jupiter/PycharmProjects/webdriver/chromedriver.exe")

driver.add_cookie(cookies)

driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
```

Exception:

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid
>   argument: missing 'cookie'   (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69
>   (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Windows
>   NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: get_cookies() will return a list with cookies but add_cookies() accept a cookie, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
driver.add_cookie(cookies)
```

you need to use

```py
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

as the `driver.add_cookie` adds one cookie per call, but `driver.get_cookies()` returns the list of cookies.

Comment: I tried that too sir,  i am getting this exception for that...............    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid cookie domain
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `refresh` method

```
driver.get(url)
driver.add_cookie({"name": "example", "value": "example"})
driver.refresh()
```

Now when the page is refreshed, it is loaded with cookies.